# How do you restart a python guess a number game?

Tags: python-3.x, numbers

I'm a newbie at python, so i couldn't figure out how to make this code repeat at the beginning again.  Here is my code:

```
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name?')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

while guessesTaken < 5:
    print('Take a guess.') 
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.') 

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
    print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + '        guesses!')

if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
```

Thanks guys, please respond soon,

Comment: yeah, but could you give an example

Comment: You mean write your code for you? No. Think about it. Where is it going to restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must have been the code you've been looking around for

```
import random

inplay = 0
x = ""
def in_play():
    global inplay, guessesTaken
    guessesTaken = 0
    if inplay == True:
        play()
    else:
        inplay = True
        play()

def play():
    global guessesTaken
    while inplay == True:
        print('Hello! What is your name?')
        myName = input()

    number = random.randint(1, 20)
    print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

    while guessesTaken < 5:
        print('Take a guess.') 
        guess = input()
        guess = int(guess)
        guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

        if guess < number:
            print('Your guess is too low.') 

        elif guess > number:
            print('Your guess is too high.')

        elif guess == number:
            break

    if guess == number:
        guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
        print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
        in_play()

    elif guess != number:
        number = str(number)
        print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + number)
        in_play()


in_play()
```

Now that was something basic but for a newbie, we totally know how it feels

***Just don't Copy Paste it but try to understand what the code does and why it does it***

Comment: Thanks all of you, especially K DawG, it really helped!

Comment: you know @user2495444 , choosing a default answer would help me and many others wasting time trying to answer this when you already have a solution

Answer (score 1):

Put your current code in a function, and then invoke it as many times as you want. For example:

```
import random

def main():
    n_games = 5
    for n in range(n_games):
        play_guessing_game()

def play_guessing_game():
    # Your code here.
    print("Blah blah")

main()
```

Even better would be to accept `n_games` as a command-line argument (`sys.argv[1]`). Even better than that would be to stop writing interactive guessing games (rant: why do people teach this stuff?) and instead learn how to write a function that does binary search.

Comment: when i do that it says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/game 2.py", line 14, in <module>
    number = random.randint(1, 20)
NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Comment: @user2495444 Include `import random` at the very top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

put your code in a function, then create another function that asks the user if he would like to play again.

```
def main():
    game = "your game"
    print(game)
    play_again()

def play_again():
    while True:
        play_again = input("Would you like to play again?(yes or no) > ")
        if play_again == "yes"
            main()
        if play_again == "no"
            exit()
        else:
            print("I'm sorry I could not recognize what you entered")
main()
```